# Randomising arrays to form an highly entropic grid

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to make a 5x5 grid using arrays with the following limitations

- Should not exceed more than 4 check marks per grid
- Should not have 2 consecutive check marks

This is what I have come up with so far, I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out how would I achieve the latter condition

```js
 let emoji = {
            0: '✅',
            1: '❓',
   }
    let grid = []
        let checkmarks = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            let row = []
            for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                let random = crypto.randomInt(0, 1000) % 2
                if (random == 0) {
                    if(checkmarks < 4) {
                    row.push(emoji[0])
                    checkmarks++
                    }
                    else {
                        row.push(emoji[1])
                    }
                } else {
                    row.push(emoji[1])
                }
            }
            grid.push(row)
        }
```

I am attempting to make it as random as possible.

Comment: Your function has a higher chance of placing checkmarks at the beginning than at the end.

Comment: Any time complexity limitations? *consecutive* means in one row or columns count too?

Comment: Consecutivity restriction for both rows and cols, no time complexity limitations, also could you please explain how would I randomise it instead of pushing it at the beginning as I do right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this answer because the accepted answer doesn't seem to produce a consistent result. I agree with most of the approach, but result just wasn't always returning 4 checkmarks (*because it seems to reset after each iteration, which can increase the maximum number of loops needed*).

But ultimately, the idea is to fill the 5x5 array with the ❓ character first, randomly select a location, verify the surrounding blocks are not ✅, and then place a ✅ if these conditions are met. If not, I instead just select a new position but keep the existing results until the needed number of ✅ have been set.

```js
let grid = [],
    rows = 5,
    cols = 5,
    maxChecks = 4,
    totalChecks = 0,
    emoji = {
      0: '✅',
      1: '❓',
   };

const _RandomChecks = () => {
  grid = [];
  totalChecks = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    grid[i] = [];
    for(let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      grid[i] = [...grid[i], emoji[1]];
    }
  }
  
  while(totalChecks < maxChecks) {
    let rndRow = parseInt(crypto.randomUUID().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").substr(-8)) % rows,
    rndCol = parseInt(crypto.randomUUID().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").substr(-8)) % cols,
    valid = (grid[rndRow][rndCol] == emoji[1]) ? true : false;
    
    if(grid[rndRow-1]?.[rndCol] && valid) valid = (grid[rndRow-1]?.[rndCol] == emoji[1]) ? true : false;
    if(grid[rndRow+1]?.[rndCol] && valid) valid = (grid[rndRow+1]?.[rndCol] == emoji[1]) ? true : false;
    if(grid[rndRow][rndCol-1] && valid) valid = (grid[rndRow][rndCol-1] == emoji[1]) ? true : false;
    if(grid[rndRow][rndCol+1] && valid) valid = (grid[rndRow][rndCol+1] == emoji[1]) ? true : false;
    
    if(valid) {
      grid[rndRow][rndCol] = emoji[0];
      totalChecks++;
    }
  }
  console.log(grid.map(row => row.join('')).join('\n'));
}

_RandomChecks();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, could you please explain how does it exactly differ in terms of time complexity as you mentioned to the reason from the accepted answer? I'd like to know, great learning from the answers here

Comment: @Zero I set up 2 CodePens to demonstrate this, but basically the accepted answer stops if it can't place a checkmark and discards the results after each itteration in the loop. My version keeps all previous checkmarks and only chooses a new location if there is a checkbox at that location or beside it. On average, my method takes about 1/3 the time. [Accepted answer with timing logged](https://codepen.io/EssXTee/pen/abYgrgm) and [here is my method with timing logged](https://codepen.io/EssXTee/pen/bGvyXVB)

Comment: This answer sent me down the rabbit hole to understand how to test randomness. Turns out it's such a big topic that I couldn't grasp in short time. At first sight I thought your solution's placement of checkmarks isn't independent to each other, well I wasn't wrong. It is independent and random enough. So ignore my previous comments (that I've deleted) if you've read them.

Comment: **Nerd Alert** : Still I'd point out that OP stated he want "no more than 4 checkmarks" which implies 0,1,2,3,4 checkmarks are all valid solutions. But your algo gives "exactly 4 checkmarks". IMO this doesn't really met the original requirement. In a sense this solution is extremely biased toward 4-solution, reducing {0, 1, 2, 3} solutions' probability straight to 0. But distribution of checkmarks in the 4-solution space is fair.

Comment: Phrasing issue, I needed 'exactly 4' check marks, I'm sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

Instead of randomly determining if a cell should be a checkmark I would rather randomly find cells that should be a checkmark.

Your current solution decreases the chance of getting a checkmark with each cell.

Created some example code for you:

```js
const emojis = ['✅', '❓']

const size = 5
const checkmarks = []

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
  while (true) {
    // get random x and y
    const x = Math.random() * size | 0
    const y = Math.random() * size | 0
    // check if x and y are far enough from existing checkmarks
    const areNeighbours = checkmarks.some(c => {
      if (c.x === x) {
        return Math.abs(c.y - y) <= 1
      }
      if (c.y === y) {
        return Math.abs(c.x - x) <= 1
      }
      return false
    })

    if (!areNeighbours) {
      checkmarks.push({
        x,
        y
      })
      break
    }
  }
}

const grid = []

for (let y = 0; y < size; y += 1) {
  grid.push([])
  for (let x = 0; x < size; x += 1) {
    const checkmark = checkmarks.find(c => c.x === x && c.y === y)
    grid[y][x] = checkmark ? emojis[0] : emojis[1]
  }
}


console.log(grid.map(row => row.join('')).join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a 5x5 board initially filled by ❓.

Next you toss 4 coins at once, each coin will landed in one cell, head or tail.

If head, place a ✅ in the cell.

Now check if non-consecutive ✅ condition is met. If not start over.

Solution:

```js
const emojis = ['✅', '❓'];

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));
}

function tossCoins(checkmarkLimit, size) {
  const positions = Array.from({ length: checkmarkLimit }, () => {
    const pos = randomInt(0, size * size);
    const tail = Math.random() > 0.5;
    if (tail) return null;
    const x = pos % 5;
    const y = (pos - x) / 5;
    return [x, y];
  })

  return positions.filter(Boolean);
}
 
function checkNonConsecutive(positions) {
  for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    const p = positions[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < positions.length; j++) {
      if (i == j) continue;
      const o = positions[j];
      const distance = Math.abs(p[0] - o[0]) + Math.abs(p[1] - o[1])
      if (distance <= 1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function main() {
  const checkmarkLimit = 4;
  const size = 5;
  const grid = Array.from({ length: size }, () => Array.from({ length: size }, () => emojis[1]));

  let positions = tossCoins(checkmarkLimit, size);
  while (!checkNonConsecutive(positions)) {
    positions = tossCoins(checkmarkLimit, size);
  }
  
  positions.forEach(([x, y]) => {
    grid[y][x] = emojis[0];
  });
  
  return grid;
}

for (let n=0; n < 10; n++) {
  console.log('round: ' + n);
  console.log(main().map(row => row.join('')).join('\n'));
}
```